# Is it safe to use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications, android-intent

### Background

Let's take the next sceneraio:

1. the user uses an app X which has multiple activities (like the gmail app).
2. after navigating the app X a bit, he goes to your app.
3. in your app, you need to start this X app using an intent, to go to a specific activity within it.
4. now the user goes to this specific activity on the app X.
5. the user presses the back button, hoping to go back to your app instead of staying on the app X.

another similar scenario:

1. the user navigates on your app between activities.
2. your app went to the background (using the home button, for example).
3. your app shows a notification that once clicked, it will open a specific activity of your app.
4. the user clicks on the notification and goes to the specific activity of your app.
5. the user presses the back button, hoping to return to the app that was shown before clicking on the notification, instead of going to the previous activity on your app that was shown the last time it left it.

It seems that the last step on both scenarios isn't the default behavior.

This is why I've searched what is the best combination of flags for this purpose.

### The problem

It seems that the only flag that can achieve the behavior i've described is [**Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK) (together with [**Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)).

According to the android API, however, this flag isn't recommended for normal use:

> Do not use this flag unless you are implementing your own top-level
>   application launcher. 
>   ...
>
> Because the default system does not include
>   graphical task management, you should not use this flag unless you
>   provide some way for a user to return back to the tasks you have
>   launched.

This information seems as confusing as the rest of the descriptions about intents.

There are other intents flags that I've seen, like [**Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) that achieve a similar result, but they have weird behaviors and/or they use high API

### The question

Is it safe to use this flag? Are there any good alternatives to it?

What is the danger of using this flag and what is the meaning of the description on the API of using it?

Answer (score 4):

In your first scenario, if your app needs to start an activity of another app, it can just start this activity **within the same task as your application**. There is no reason to use any special Intent flags for this (you don't need `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` or `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`). In step 5 of your scenario, the user will return to your application (because BACK just takes him to the previous activity in the current task). This is the standard, default behaviour.

In your second scenario, my first response is "that isn't the standard behaviour". That means that users probably won't expect to be able to **go back to the task that they were doing prior to clicking on the notification**. However, if you really want to implement this, then I would suggest that you create a special Activity that is launched from the notification and this special Activity should have a different `taskAffinity` than the rest of the Activities in your application. In this case, when the special Activity is launched from the notification, it will **not bring your application's task to the foreground**. It will just create a new task containing just the special Activity. When the special Activity is showing, the user can press the BACK key and this will return him to the task that he was working on prior to clicking on your notification.

In general you should NOT use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`. The main reason is that if you have several tasks containing your application (or parts of it), it is pretty much impossible for the user to return to a specific one. There is no way to provide different launch icons or different application names (for the different tasks)(, so that the user will see multiple tasks in the "recent tasks" list, but will not be able to tell which one is which. You will have a hard time cleaning up what you are doing and you will just make more problems than you can deal with. There are about a million side effects of using this flag and for general applicaitons there is just no need to do it.

Comment: about the first scenario, sometimes you must use the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK (for example when running from a service or a notification). Also, if the user sees the app on the recent apps, he should see 2 apps and not ours as it will show the third party app image on our app's thumbnail. this is a bad experience. about the second scenario solution, that is just too much work since there are already activities on the app, so why make it more complex and add multiple activities for each kind of notification just for notifications feature...

Comment: and about the last part of your answer, i'm sorry, but i didn't understand this part. having multiple tasks on the app isn't something that is hard to handle. all share the same process. the "recent tasks" as shown to the user won't create a new one for each task. only if you set on the manifest the taskAffinity to "" , it will happen. even if you add both flags , it won't cause android to have multiple tasks on the recent-tasks of your app. maybe it was the case on old android versions? I'm running on 4.1.2.

Comment: Well then, it sounds like you already know all the answers. So why did you ask the question?

Comment: that's because i've read the API, and they have a warning about it. if there is an alternative that has a nice behavior, i think it's better to use it. also, if it's not that important to use this flag, i would also like to know about it.

Comment: Sorry, your other comment (regarding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` makes no sense. If you want to create multiple tasks, and Android only shows 1 of them in the recent tasks list, then how can the user go back to the other task? He can't. So what is the point of creating multiple tasks? As the documentation says, _"...you need to provide some way for a user to return back to the tasks you have launched."_

Comment: no, i meant the user won't see multiple tasks on the recent-tasks, for your app. if you use this flag on another app, and then press home and show the recent-tasks, you can see one for your app, and another one for the other app. it won't create multiple tasks of your own app.

Comment: Unless the other app is already running in a task, in which case the other app will now have 2 entries in the running tasks list :-(

Comment: no, if the app is already running in a task, it won't create 2 thumbnails for the user in the recent-tasks list. just try it out. i've tried both gmail and the play store. however, the weird thing would be when after i go to gmail from my app, and then try to navigate there instead of clicking back button. it still works, but then when i click back, it won't show my app. it will show the app that was opened before (or the launcher, of course).

Comment: I've re-checked the second scenario, and my solution doesn't work well on it (or maybe i forgot what else I should do).  i wonder if there would be any implications of having a new activity just for handling notifications as you've written.

Comment: I don't think so. I've used this approach before. What exactly is your problem now?

Comment: i don't know. i think that using intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); , and then just use onNewIntent , will be just fine for most cases. however, it could ruin the entire backstack of the activities. i guess it depends on the needs of the app.